# Same $PATH showing multiple times though I have added them once

Tags: fish

Here are my path variables

```
> echo $PATH | tr " " "\n" | sort
/bin
/home/ismail/bin
/home/ismail/.dotfiles/.cargo/bin
/home/ismail/.dotfiles/.cargo/bin
/home/ismail/.dotfiles/.resources/bash-scripts
/home/ismail/.dotfiles/.resources/git-scripts
/home/ismail/.dotfiles/.resources/python-scripts
/home/ismail/.dotfiles/.resources/zsh-scripts
/home/ismail/.local/bin
/home/ismail/.local/bin
/home/ismail/.nvm/versions/node/v20.2.0/bin
/sbin
/snap/bin
/snap/bin
/usr/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/games
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
```

I am very much positive that I have added these path once using `fish_add_path`. Here is the `config.fish` file:

```
set -l RESOURCES ~/.dotfiles/.resources
fish_add_path -g $RESOURCES/bash-scripts
fish_add_path -g $RESOURCES/python-scripts
fish_add_path -g $RESOURCES/git-scripts
fish_add_path -g ~/bin
fish_add_path -g ~/.local/bin
fish_add_path -g ~/.dotfiles/.cargo/bin
```

Here, I did not add `/home/ismail/.dotfiles/.resources/zsh-scripts`. This variable was set for zsh.

Where does fish shell get the environment variables from? How can I stop having duplicates? How to not have paths that I do not want to not being imported from other shells.

Comment: fish gets its environment variables from the environment it inherits, per Unix.

One possibility is that you have configured fish to launch from a zsh shell, thereby inheriting zsh variables. Another possibility is that you have added `zsh-scripts` to some global config such as `/etc/paths`.

A good starting point is that you added `zsh-scripts` for zsh: how did you do that? And how do you launch fish?

Comment: I use zsh as the default shell. I have changed the first line of .zshrc to `fish`.

Comment: The documentation says "There are multiple ways to switch to fish (or any other shell) as your default. The simplest method is to set your terminal emulator (eg GNOME Terminal, Apple’s Terminal.app, or Konsole) to start fish directly. " However, i use alacritty and not sure how to set fish as the default shell there.

Comment: Remove that line from zshrc, and just start zsh. Is that zsh-scripts directory in $PATH? If it is, then you need to remove it from the zsh configuration. $PATH is exported, so it is passed on to child processes, like a fish started from zsh.

Comment: And duplicate paths: fish_add_path will only add a path if it isn't included already. That means something *after* your fish_add_path calls also adds it. This can be another script, or a tool you `source` the output of.